# images appearing black when uploaded php imagecreatefromjpeg

Tags: php, image

The worked until recently, just as I'm about to attend an interview, but the code no longer does what it should.

The page, fetches the list of images, described in the database, uploaded by the user then, using the file name, collects the image from a directory.

When uploading, the user simply browses their hard drive and taps the upload button on the form. The image is loaded to preload-images/ directory and a copy is resized to thumbnail size and placed in another directory preload-images-thumbs/, then the page mails the administrator to approve the photo.

This all worked fine, but the only record I have of it working was back in September 2016. Now it only creates black images, albeit resized correctly, but no image.

I've checked a few similar issues on here and other sites, but nothing seems to work. I've even been in touch with the host to up the memory in php.ini

Here's some of the code if anyone can help...

```
<?php
function make_thumb($src,$dest,$desired_width, $desired_height, $ext) {
    /* read the source image */

    if ( $ext == 'jpg' || ext == 'jpeg') {
        $source_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
    }
    if ( $ext == 'png') {
        $source_image = imagecreatefrompng($src);
    }


    $source_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
    $width = imagesx($source_image);
    $height = imagesy($source_image);
    /* find the "desired height" of this thumbnail, relative to the desired width  */
    $desired_height = floor($height*($desired_width/$width));
    /* create a new, "virtual" image */

    if ( $ext == 'jpg' || ext == 'jpeg') {
        imagejpeg($virtual_image,$dest);
    }
    if ( $ext == 'png') {
        imagepng($virtual_image,$dest);
    }

    $virtual_image = imagecreatetruecolor($desired_width,$desired_height);
    /* copy source image at a resized size */
    imagecopyresized($virtual_image,$source_image,300,0,0,0,$desired_width,$desired_height,$width,$height);
    /* create the physical thumbnail image to its destination */
    imagejpeg($virtual_image,$dest);
}

/* function:  returns files from dir */
function get_files($images_dir,$exts = array('jpg', 'jpeg')) {
    $files = array();
    if($handle = opendir($images_dir)) {
        while(false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
            $extension = strtolower(get_file_extension($file));
            if($extension && in_array($extension,$exts)) {
                $files[] = $file;
            }
        }
        closedir($handle);
    }
    return $files;
}

/* function:  returns a file's extension */
function get_file_extension($file_name) {
    return substr(strrchr($file_name,'.'),1);
}


/** settings **/
$images_dir = 'preload-images/';
$thumbs_dir = 'preload-images-thumbs/';
$thumbs_width = 200;
$images_per_row = 4;

/** generate photo gallery **/
$image_files = get_files($images_dir);
if(count($image_files)) {
    $index = 0;
    foreach($image_files as $index=>$file) {
        $index++;
        $thumbnail_image = $thumbs_dir.$file;
        if(!file_exists($thumbnail_image)) {
            $extension = get_file_extension($thumbnail_image);
            if($extension) {
                make_thumb($images_dir.$file,$thumbnail_image,$thumbs_width, $thumbs_height, $extension);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Just to add, all of the older images, pre sept 2106, work fine. I've even tried making copies and renaming the older images to try and reload them to see if its something to do with the image formats, but these still process black boxes.

Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: any errors logged in the php error log? The function `make_thumb` has a logic test to determine, based upon the file extension, which routine to use to generate the new image. You then proceed to use `$source_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);` regardless of logic test. The code then proceeds to use `$virtual_image` but that is defined AFTER it is called by `imagejpeg` or `imagepng`

Comment: no errors logged for this php file - the page was written back in 2010 and  worked up until earlier this year, but the only evidence I've got left after trailing over and over again is an image loaded in sept 2016

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tryed your code and fixed some notices and a wrong setting ($dst_x) in imagecopyresized function..
To high numbers in the $dst_x makes the image go "out of bounds"

```
 <?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);


function make_thumb($src,$dest,$desired_width, $desired_height, $ext) {
  /* read the source image */

if ( $ext == 'jpg' || ext == 'jpeg') {
$source_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
}
if ( $ext == 'png') {
$source_image = imagecreatefrompng($src);
}


  $source_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
  $width = imagesx($source_image);
  $height = imagesy($source_image);
  /* find the "desired height" of this thumbnail, relative to the desired width  */
  $desired_height = floor($height*($desired_width/$width));
  /* create a new, "virtual" image */
$virtual_image = imagecreatetruecolor($desired_width,$desired_height); # removed here because off notice.

if ( $ext == 'jpg' || ext == 'jpeg') {
imagejpeg($virtual_image,$dest);
}
if ( $ext == 'png') {
imagepng($virtual_image,$dest);
}


  /* copy source image at a resized size */
  #changed 300 into 0
  imagecopyresized($virtual_image,$source_image,0,0,0,0,$desired_width,$desired_height,$width,$height);
  /* create the physical thumbnail image to its destination */
  imagejpeg($virtual_image,$dest);
}

/* function:  returns files from dir */
function get_files($images_dir,$exts = array('jpg', 'jpeg')) {
  $files = array();
  if($handle = opendir($images_dir)) {
    while(false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
      $extension = strtolower(get_file_extension($file));
      if($extension && in_array($extension,$exts)) {
        $files[] = $file;
      }
    }
    closedir($handle);
  }
  return $files;
}

/* function:  returns a file's extension */
function get_file_extension($file_name) {
  return substr(strrchr($file_name,'.'),1);
}


/** settings **/
$images_dir = 'preload-images/';
$thumbs_dir = 'preload-images-thumbs/';
$thumbs_width = 200; 
$thumbs_height = null; # added because off notice..
$images_per_row = 4;

/** generate photo gallery **/
$image_files = get_files($images_dir);
if(count($image_files)) {
  $index = 0;
  foreach($image_files as $index=>$file) {
    $index++;
    $thumbnail_image = $thumbs_dir.$file;
    if(!file_exists($thumbnail_image)) {
      $extension = get_file_extension($thumbnail_image);
      if($extension) {
        make_thumb($images_dir.$file,$thumbnail_image,$thumbs_width, $thumbs_height, $extension);
      }
    }
  }
}

?>
```

Comment: perfect! Thanks very much! I've been pulling my hair out wondering whats going on with it since yesterday!